# cannot drop index on MariaDb table?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have difficulty dropping index of a table `userprofile_userprofile`:

Here are the indexes:

```
MariaDB [djdb]> SHOW INDEX FROM userprofile_userprofile;
+-------------------------+------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table                   | Non_unique | Key_name      | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------------------------+------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| userprofile_userprofile |          0 | PRIMARY       |            1 | id          | A         |       14566 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| userprofile_userprofile |          1 | id-userid-idx |            1 | id          | A         |       14566 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| userprofile_userprofile |          1 | id-userid-idx |            2 | user_id     | A         |       14566 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------------------------+------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

When I try:

```
MariaDB [djdb]> ALTER TABLE  userprofile_userprofile DROP INDEX id-userid-idx;
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-userid-idx' at line 1
```

I have also tried

```
DROP INDEX  id-userid-idx ON  userprofile_userprofile;
```

But get the same error. 
I'm wondering what's wrong here and how can I do drop the index?

Comment: Well, I figured out. I needed to add backtick `\``around the index name.

Comment: Anything with irregular characters in it will require that. This is why using dashes in column names is bad news.

Comment: I see. Is underline also considered `irregular`?

Comment: no underscores are fine from my experience. It is a math engine too. hyphens fall into the irregular category.

Comment: I concur with Drew. The usual definition for a simple name is anything including a-z or underscore. That is names like `user_profile` are preferable to things like `UserProfile` or `user-profile`.